# How can I get all successors of a given node of a graph?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a `scalax.collection.Graph` and want to get a collection of all successors of a given node.

```
import scalax.collection.Graph

...

val node = Graph('f~>'g, 'g~>'y, 'f~>'h).get('f)
val successors = <statement to get successors of f> // = collection with g and h
```

I am just learning Scala and already searched and tried for several hours how to do this, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> import scalax.collection.Graph
import scalax.collection.Graph

scala> import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._
import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._

scala> val node = Graph('f~>'g, 'g~>'y, 'f~>'h).get('f)
node: scalax.collection.Graph[Symbol,scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge]#NodeT = 'f

scala> val successors = node.outgoing.map(_.to.value)
successors: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Symbol] = Set('g, 'h)
```

Comment: This works and also results in `'f` being a successor if the edge `'f~>'f` is present. I actually found another solution `val successors = node.diSuccessors`, however this does not result in `'f` being a successor if the edge `'f~>'f` is present.